# Exporting image from QGIS precisely on layer extent?

Tags: qgis, layers, export, layouts

I have a map of the word, the bottom layer is a world raster layer from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/) and on top of it several vector layer.

Using QGIS 3.4.4, I need to export image without a background, it needs to be precisely on the raster extent.

When I use the Layout manager (Print composer) I cannot get a perfect result, there is always a background.

So, I am looking for a way to perfect extent choosing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QGIS 3.4 there is a very useful tool for map importing by extent.

The Import/Export panel enable image,PDF and DXF.

[image]

In the "Save Map as image" panel the image extent is calculate from layer, canvas extent or by hand drawing.
[image]

The project layers, raster and vector, are listed in the "Calculate from Layer". The map extent is determined by the selected layer.

In this example, I choose the raster layer. The imported layer was precisely on the raster extent, without background.

[image]